# Spring Boot error with a repository/entity, "not a managed type"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, inversion-of-control

I know that similar questions have been asked before on this forum, but none of the proposed solutions helped me, so I am writing a separate question. The code is from the spring boot course on youtube (https://youtu.be/zvR-Oif_nxg)(im stuck about 2:21:00), but this error also occurs when I tried to do the course on the spring boot site. The full text of the error is:

---

`"Error creating bean with name 'departmentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'departmentService': Error creating bean with name 'departmentServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'departmentRepository': Error creating bean with name 'departmentRepository' defined in com.kamilosinni.course.repository.DepartmentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.kamilosinni.course.entity.Department"`

---

main app class (CourseApplication.java):

```java
package com.kamilosinni.course;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;



@SpringBootApplication

public class CourseApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

DepartmentController.java:

```java
package com.kamilosinni.course.controller;


import com.kamilosinni.course.entity.Department;
import com.kamilosinni.course.service.DepartmentService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DepartmentController {

    @Autowired
   private DepartmentService departmentService;
    @GetMapping("/departments")
    public Department saveDepartment(@RequestBody Department department)
    {
        return departmentService.saveDepartment(department);

    }
}
```

Department.java:

```java
package com.kamilosinni.course.entity;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long departmentId;
    private String departmentName;
    private String departmentAdress;
    private String departmentCode;

    public Long getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public void setDepartmentId(Long departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return departmentName;
    }

    public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
    }

    public String getDepartmentAdress() {
        return departmentAdress;
    }

    public void setDepartmentAdress(String departmentAdress) {
        this.departmentAdress = departmentAdress;
    }

    public String getDepartmentCode() {
        return departmentCode;
    }

    public void setDepartmentCode(String departmentCode) {
        this.departmentCode = departmentCode;
    }

    public Department(Long departmentId, String departmentName, String departmentAdress, String departmentCode) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
        this.departmentAdress = departmentAdress;
        this.departmentCode = departmentCode;
    }
    public Department(){}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Department{" +
                "departmentId=" + departmentId +
                ", departmentName='" + departmentName + '\'' +
                ", departmentAdress='" + departmentAdress + '\'' +
                ", departmentCode='" + departmentCode + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

DepartmentRepository.java:

```java
package com.kamilosinni.course.repository;

import com.kamilosinni.course.entity.Department;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {}
```

DepartmentService.java:

```java
package com.kamilosinni.course.service;

import com.kamilosinni.course.entity.Department;



public interface DepartmentService {
    Department saveDepartment(Department department);
}
```

DepartmentServiceImpl.java:

```java
package com.kamilosinni.course.service;

import com.kamilosinni.course.entity.Department;
import com.kamilosinni.course.repository.DepartmentRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class DepartmentServiceImpl implements DepartmentService{



@Autowired
    DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

    DepartmentServiceImpl(){}
    @Override
    public Department saveDepartment(Department department) {
        return departmentRepository.save(department);
    }
}
```

i tried to add additional annotations to the main class:

```java
package com.kamilosinni.course;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.kamilosinni.course.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.kamilosinni.course.repository")
public class CourseApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Also i tried to move the class to the main package with the main class and addthe `@NoRepositoryBean` annotation to the `DepartmentRepository`, that didn't do anything either

Edit: if i replace `javax` imports with `jakarta` in Department.java, there is no error. In addition, in the guides on the official site, `javax` is used all the time, which is quite strange, because even the rewritten code does not work. Maybe the configuration is incorrect? Or maybe dependencies.

```java
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
```

I also add my pom.xml file, it may be helpful:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kamilosinni</groupId>
    <artifactId>course</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>course</name>
    <description>Spring boot course</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[File structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBLEc.png)

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue.

In my case, the problem was :

1. In wrong dependency (`javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2`), removed it
2. Wrong imports for `@Entity` and `@Id` - replaced them with :

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
```

Seems that `javax.persistence` was replaced by `jakarta.persistence` last year. Anyway, spring data JPA examples [now uses jakarta package](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/main/jpa/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/simple/User.java)

Answer (score 0):

in the class DepartmentServiceImpl there is no public constructor. It is needed by Spring for dependency injection.

**Solution**

Either add public identifier to the constructor or remove it. A public constructor without arguments will be created by Java internally (if no other constructor present).

**Edited** after you added the pom.xml to the question:

Please remove this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried both solutions both adding `public` and removing the entire constructor declaration, but unfortunately, still the same problem :(

Comment: When I remove this dependency, I can't use import 'javax' anymore. Should I use 'jakarta' instead of 'javax' and it will be the same? (I'm asking because both guides i am converting use javax i dont know if jakarta will be the correct form)

Comment: jakarta is the correct one to work smoothly with the other Spring dependencies you have already.