# Service required a bean of type 'Repository' that could not be found in Springboot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

i am new to springboot.
i try to run with my data using jpa i meet this problem.
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.service.MemberService required a bean of type 'com.example.repository.MemberRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.repository.MemberRepository' in your configuration.

this is my project structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJk8p.png)

MemberService.java

```
@Service
public class MemberService {

    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MemberService(MemberRepository memberRepository) {

        this.memberRepository = memberRepository;
    }

    public List<Member> getAllMembers() {
        return memberRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

MemberController.java

```
@Controller
public class MemberController {

    private final MemberService memberService;

    @Autowired
    public MemberController(MemberService memberService) {
        this.memberService = memberService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/members")
    public String getAllMembers(Model model) {
        List<Member> members = memberService.getAllMembers();
        model.addAttribute("members", members);
        return "members";
    }
}
```

MemberRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<Member, Long> {
}
```

Member.java

```
@Entity
public class Member {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String kana;
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    private String birthPlace;
    private String ki;
    private String link;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

Main method

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        String serverPort = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("server.port");
        String contextPath = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("server.servlet.context-path", "");
        System.out.println("Application is running at: http://localhost:" + serverPort + contextPath);
    }

}
```

i check some stackoverflow questions like me but i don't find the right method to solve.
i will be thankful if you give me the right solution and tell me how i change my code.
thanks for you reply i really need your help.

Comment: Let me guess "following" a tutorial, decided you needed Spring Boot 3, tutorial is for Sprng Boot 2. You copy pasted classes and "fixed" the compiler errors by adding additional dependencies to your application. Dependencies likee `persistence-api` or old Hibernate versions.

Comment: @M. Deinum thanks for your reply! my tutorial version is 2 actually,but the more exact solution i still don't understand...sorry..Can you tell me more exact solution to this problem? thank you!

Comment: If there is a problem regarding the tutorial you follow you should contact them for further investigation so that they can fix their buggy crap. Otherwise, please grab an up-to-date tutorial which runs properly with a current dependency chain. Fixing old and crappy tutorials is not what SO is build for.

Comment: I'm not sure if adding comments makes you see them, but I have solved this problem.it's totally version incompatible problem.actually  persistence-api is old and not compatible with springboot3 and my Hibernate version is old...but i find so much time to get this....actually to notice the debug console information is important.thanks,now i change to 3 and build my project again. @M. Deinum
but it maybe give me the idea that i should think if version is wrong when i face the familiar problem.

Comment: If you are following a tutorial **follow the tutorial**. Including the versions of the software being used. If they use version 2.6 or 2.7.x stay within that version and follow the tutorial. Don't upgrade to newer versions as that will make the tutorial useless as things change between versions and if you move to Spring Boot 3 that is a major overhaul for the move from JavaEE to JakartaEE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

persistence-api problem:

> [Spring Boot error with a repository/entity, "not a managed type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75965177/spring-boot-error-with-a-repository-entity-not-a-managed-type)

and build a new project:
https://start.spring.io/

and check if dependency version is able to compatible.

Comment: then maybe next i have the problem i should give pom.xml , package import specifically and config file that will be better...